# Text data in RowHeader

Tags: android, tableview

How to display any text data (names, cities etc) in row header? By default, it showing and fits only 1-3 number chars, but when you try to change numbers to words, row header don,t changing its size and shows only part of that words

P.s We talking about android library TableView by evrencoskun

Comment: Show us first your approach, this is not for do your work

Comment: I tried to do the same way like auto-size in cell layout - when we binding RowHeaderViewHolder, do wrap content and request layout for each row header cell but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, In [the Sample app](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/table_view_row_header_layout.xml), Row Header has a content wıdth value;

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/root"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:background="@color/cell_background_color"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/row_header_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cell_height">
```

So, to achieve what you want, you need to either change the constant row_header_width value or you can set the Row Header width size using the below code;

```
tableView.setRowHeaderWidth(int rowHeaderWidth)
```

Comment: yes, i already understood this but if i want to margin my RowHeader to longest item in RowHeaderList... I need to call setRowHeaderWidth every "onBindRowHeaderViewHolder" or what?

Comment: Unfortunately, TableView supports only a fixed-size row header. It doesn't calculate each row width values to resize them. Resizing width value feature is only for columns instead of row headers.

Comment: okay, but for detecting "fixed size" can i do something before "setAll" function?
I.e i have immutable list of row headers (strings) but they has differend length. Can i calculate row header width as longest string in my list before creating TableView?

Comment: Yes, you can calculate a row header width value considering your row header contents. And setRowHeaderWidth function could be worked before setAll function. But It will not give the same behaviour as the TableView has. Because it calculates the value considering the appeared views rather than texts. But better than nothing. :) Calculate a width value considering a text size and see it whether it is the proper value.